# Set progress message/state from custom action possible?

Tags: install4j

We wrote a custom action to deploy some artifacts to our glassfish server. Now we wanted to display the names of the artifacts to the message-text of the progess bar. Therefore we want to set the text directly from the custom action instead using a separate `set-progress`-action. Is this possible? We want to avoid a bunch of `custom-action/set-progress-message` entries in our configuration although we can recap these inside a action group.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Call

```
context.getProgressInterface().setStatusMessage("Your text");
```

in your code. The progress interface also has methods for changing the percentage, the indeterminate state and the detail message.